# Updating existing PostgreSQL database with OSM data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, database, osm2pgsql

I currently work on the project which is directly working with the geo data of the country where I live. The database we have is quite huge, containing not only the geo data but also some other stuff. The issue it that that geo data is outdated, meaning that the street names may be wrong and etc. I want to update it using the OSM data.

So my first step was to get OSM data, I have exported OSM data of my country from https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/kazakhstan.html. Then I have created a new PostgreSQL database in DBeaver and imported data to this DB. Now I have a new DB with all up-to-date geo data, there are 4 main tables: osm_planet_point, osm_planet_line, osm_planet_polygon and osm_planet_roads.

Now the problem is that the structure of this freshly created DB is very different from what we currently have, for instance we have a table districts which has info only about districts - like districtname(in several languages), typeofdistrict, geometry and a lot of other different columns. However the OSM DB, for example, has a table polygons as mentioned before which contains polygons representing areas, such as buildings, land use areas, and administrative boundaries - so there are cities, regions, buildings and etc.

I am very inexperienced in working with databases in general, so I am not sure what is the best way to update our current DB. Is there a way to transform OSM DB to make it similar to what we have, or maybe there is a way to somehow select some rows and update them manually.
The question is vague, I understand that, I am here only to get advices on how to make it more efficiently.

Comment: There are columns in the osm tables that you can use to extract the districts, cities, etc.  Another option is to download the shp.zip from the link you posted.  Here's the info about what's included http://download.geofabrik.de/osm-data-in-gis-formats-free.pdf.  Another option is something like the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS.  There's also the osm overpass api..  There's no easy way to convert one data structure into another, existing data structure.

Comment: This looks interesting - https://osm-boundaries.com/